# Parameters that are also functions - semantic syntax highlighting in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I've been playing around with customizing the semantic syntax highlighting on the new VSCode April 2020 release (coding in Typescript-React), and I've run into a problem. I changed parameter types to be in italics, but parameters that are of type `function` don't change. Instead, they adopt the semantic highlighting for a function. Inspecting with the theme inspector shows that the parameters of type `function`, when used in the code, don't have any scopes or semantic information that identifies them as parameters anymore.

I want to be able to define a new style for types that are both parameters and functions. I can change the parameter style inside the function definition of the parameters with the TextMate `variable.parpameter.tsx` scope, but the highlighting is lost when I call or use the functions.

Example setup with parameter of type `function` italicised in declaration (`variable.parameter.tsx` scope) but not when used in function body:
[image]

`arg1` definition - theme inspection box
[image]

`arg1` use in function body - theme inspection box
[image]